# jQuery, AJAX, PHP data exchange issue

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I try to post the values from the input field with the jquery.ajax function to a php file. The php part must insert the data into an mysql database, generate a unique pincode and return the pincode by json to the jquery code.

But when submitting the form nothing happens...

When I go directly to the main.php file in my browser, it show me a unique pincode and the php script even insert the pincode in the database. So I think the JSON part goes wrong, but I can't figure out why.

I hope somebody can show me what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be fantastic!

**Underneath code is the working code!**

HTML part:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>AJAX PHP JSON Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("form#userForm").submit(function() {
                var inputFname = $('#inputFname').attr('value');
                var inputLname = $('#inputLname').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "main.php",
                    data: {inputFname: inputFname,inputLname: inputLname},
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("p.succesText").html(data.jsCode);
                        $("form#userForm").hide();
                        $("div.success").fadeIn();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        $("form#userForm").hide();
                        $("p.errorHead").html("Something went wrong.");
                        $("p.errorText").text("ResponseText: " + xhr.responseText
                                            + "Statuscode: " + xhr.status
                                            + "ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                        $("div.error").fadeIn();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="MiddleWhite">
        <form id="userForm" method="post" name="userForm" action="">
        <label for="inputFname" class="LabelForInput">
            Enter your Forename
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="inputFname" id="inputFname" class="TextInput"
            size="20" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="inputLname" class="LabelForInput">
            Enter your Surname
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="inputLname" id="inputLname" class="TextInput"
            size="20" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="Button">
            Generate code</button>
        </form>
        <div class="success" style="display: none;">
            <p class="succesText">
            </p>
            <p class="checkCallText">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="error" style="display: none;">
            <p class="errorHead">
            </p>
            <p class="errorText">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP part:

```php
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $log = array();


        $varFname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputFname"]);
        $varLname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inputLname"]);

        //Make Database connection
        $db = mysql_connect("192.168.178.254","root","852456");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("Ajax" ,$db);

        //Generate code and check if code already exists in the database
        do
        {
            $varCode = rand(10000, 99999);
            $dbCheckCode = "";
            $dbCheckCode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableAjax WHERE code='$varCode'");
        }
        while (mysql_fetch_array($dbCheckCode) !== false);

        //Save the Form data in the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TableRecordcall (fname, lname, code) VALUES (".PrepSQL($varFname) . ", " .PrepSQL($varLname) . ", " .PrepSQL($varCode) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);  

        //Return code to frontend
        $log['jsCode'] = $varCode;

        echo json_encode($log);


    //Clean SQL statement
    function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        return($value);
    }   

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you didn't use

`return false;`

in summit callback to prevent default form submission. Change your js code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("form#submit").submit(function() {
                var inputFname = $('#inputFname').attr('value');
                var inputLname = $('#inputLname').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "main.php",
                    data: {inputFname: inputFname,inputLname: inputLname},
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("p.succesText").html(data.jsCode);
                        $("form#submit").hide();
                        $("div.success").fadeIn();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        $("form#submit").hide();
                        $("p.errorHead").html("Something went wrong.");
                        $("p.errorText").text("ResponseText: " + xhr.responseText
                                            + "Statuscode: " + xhr.status
                                            + "ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                        $("div.error").fadeIn();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Joy, the return false statement works! Thanks for your answer! By the way, I thought the single quotes were used for text and without quotes to call a variable?

Comment: In object's key's you can either use quotes or use them without quotes. But Using quotes is better as then there's no possibility of keyword conflict. But without quote version is more commonly used. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the JQuery API [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> **Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form**, such as *submit*, *length*, or *method*. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see DOMLint.

You wrote

```
<form id="submit" method="post" name="submit" action="">
```

Try to change id/name of the form.

Comment: Changed the id / name in userForm but unfortunately without result.

Answer (score 0):

In $.ajax replace

```
data: {'inputFname': inputFname,'inputLname': inputLname},
```

by

```
data: {inputFname: inputFname,inputLname: inputLname},
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Nuno Costa, I thought the single quotes were used for text and without quotes to call a variable?

Comment: Before colon no single quotes, after colon you only have single quotes if it is no variable.